# How to add field alias mappings for deserialization

Tags: php, symfony, deserialization

I am new to serialization of objects and am having trouble trying to figure out how/where I can insert a mapping between object fields and CSV headers.

I am currently creating a CSV upload form and trying to use CSVEncoder to deserialize rows of the CSV into an array of objects.

Now, this works when headers are perfect but I was hoping to add some kind of header mapping to the CSVEncoder to map headers to fields.

Example

```
class Person
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $email;
}
```

CSV Headers like the below will map rows perfectly

```
'name,age,email'
```

but I'd like to add some kind of mapping to allow headers like these to also map to the appropriate field

```
'full name,aged,email address'
```

References:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Maybe my Googling skills aren't great because I thought this would be a common occurrence when trying to deserialize CSVs.

I do have a non-serialized version that reads the file and converts the rows to objects but it is very slow and I'd like to improve this code (and my skills) by doing things 'properly'.

In this other version I read the header row, compare it with an associative array that maps the correct header and an array of acceptable aliases, and then rewrite the headers with their proper headers.

I could do this again before passing the file to the CSVEncoder but am wondering if there is a better less ugly way of doing this.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a NameConverter, check this https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#converting-property-names-when-serializing-and-deserializing

So, your name converter could looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\NameConverterInterface;

class MappingNameConverter implements NameConverterInterface {
    public function __construct(array $mapping) {
        $this->mapping = $mapping;
    }

    public function denormalize($propertyName)
    {
        return $this->mapping[$propertyName];
    }
}
```

and you should use it like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\CsvEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

$mapping = ['full name' => 'name', 'aged' => 'age', ...];
$nameConverter = new MappingNameConverter($mapping);
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, $nameConverter);

$serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [new CsvEncoder()]);
```

I didn't test the code but something similar should work :)

Comment: Thanks!  I did read that but I totally misunderstood it.  I thought it was just adding 'org_' to the values rather than the keys.

Comment: Just some lines of code that explains the concept. Well done Vincent. Thank you! I don't know why the Symfony docs are so kryptic sometimes.